I was having my money in SafePal wallet and it is linked with blsfw.top, I have been offered 12 ETH, and asked me to pay verification fee is it true
I was having money in my SafePal wallet and it is linked with DApp blsfw.top, I have been first asked to fulfil the standard amount of 15000 USDT, to get the offered 12 ETH as an airdrop and now they are asking me to pay verification fee of 11629 USDT to get the reward plus my money which is already in the SafePal wallet, is it true. How can I get my money back now, as the money is not in my SafePal wallet, as it has been taken by DApp blsfw.top, I am really upset and it is all my hard earned money. Pls help me out I don’t want the reward pls return only my money

Without more details it seems like you were victim of a scam. Unfortunately there isn't much you could do.
